# Parsing a URL from XML with &amp; in it

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch

I am trying to parse a URL with an `&amp;` in the URL:

```
ViewArticle.dbml?DB_OEM_ID=1800&amp;ATCLID=3664162
```

..but using NSXMLParser, all i get is `1800ATCL`. It completely ignores the `&amp;`.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if (qName) {
        elementName = qName;
    }


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty = [NSMutableString string];
    }else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty = [NSMutableString string];
    }else {
        self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty = nil;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{     
    if (qName) {
        elementName = qName;
    }

    _currentElement = elementName;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        self.currentNewsObject.title = self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        self.currentNewsObject.link = self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty) {
        [self.contentOfCurrentNewsProperty appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**Edit:** I did a little more testing and the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>`
is what is messing it up, but this is embedded in the xml file, any way to get around it?**

Comment: Could you reformat your question and put a little more information?

Answer (score 2):

thanks with the y'all's help i was able to get it going using

```
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
    myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\"windows-1252\"" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"my str is %@", myStr);

NSData* aData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];
```

all works now, once again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(dbr: the original poster is using NSXMLParser, not NSXMLDocument, so there is no `setCharacterEncoding` method for him to override.)

To the OP: To test your situation, I wrote a simple command-line utility that uses NSXMLParser to parse an XML document with the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>` processing instruction. The parsing always fails, and the error code is 31, which corresponds to the enumeration `NSXMLParserUnknownEncodingError`.

To solve this problem, you may have to pre-process your input data. One way of doing this might be to use `[NSString stringWithCString:yourCstring encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]`, where `yourCstring` is a standard C `char*` containing your XML. You can then remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>` processing instruction, convert the NSString to an NSData, and pass it into the NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could override the encoding using [`setCharacterEncoding`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLDocument/setCharacterEncoding:)

> setCharacterEncoding:
>
> Sets the character encoding of the receiver to encoding,
>
> `- (void)setCharacterEncoding:(NSString *)encoding`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - encoding
>
>   A string that specifies an encoding; it must match the name of an IANA character set. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets for a list of valid encoding specifiers.
>
>   Typically the encoding is specified in the XML declaration of a document that is processed, but it can be set at any time. If the specified encoding does not match the actual encoding, parsing of the document might fail.